# Taking derivatives of the integration bounds

Tags: calculus, derivatives

It has been a while since I took rudimentary calculus classes, so I might be slipping on the basics. I tripping on how to differentiate the lower and upper bounds of an integral.

For example, lets say that $f:=e^{\int^t_0 R(s) ds}$ and we want to differentiate this with respect to $t$. The following ensues
$$
\frac{d}{dt} f = \frac{d}{dt} e^{\int^t_0 R(s) ds} = R(t)e^{\int^t_0 R(s) ds}
$$
I do not see how this is a direct result. Am I missing some steps in between? Or am I missing a basic theorem in calculus? Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: I was going to ask that question later after I asked a question regarding derivatives of derivative orders, but you outtimed me. (If thats a word)

Comment: Well, actually I thought about it, and I came up with that definite integral is just $\int^a_bf(x)\,dx=F(a)-F(b)$, you can derive from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result can be delivered as follow:

Let $A(s)$ be an antiderivative of $R(s)$, $\frac d{ds}(A(s))=R(s)$.

Thus $\int_0^t R(s) = A(t) - A(0)$.

$$\frac d {dt} f = \frac d {dt} e^{A(t) - A(0)} = e^{A(t) - A(0)} \times \frac d {dt}(A(t)-A(0))$$ (chain rule)
$$=e^{A(t) - A(0)} \times (R(t)-R(0))$$ (linearity of derivative)
$$=e^{\int_0^t R(s)}\times (R(t)-R(0))$$ (definition of antiderivative)

Answer (score 1):

You have a chain rule error: $(e^f)'=f'e^f$.

So:
$$
\frac{d}{dt} f = \frac{d}{dt} e^{\int^t_0 R(s) ds} = R(t)\color{red}{e^{\int^t_0 R(s) ds}}
$$

Comment: Isn't this supposed to be a comment?

Comment: Am I breaking a rule I am unaware of?

Comment: Actually I don't know...nevermind.

Comment: I've seen arguments about what should be posted as an answer vs comment, or when a hint should be provided instead of a complete solution. And I can understand those perspectives. Sometimes I will provide a hint instead, sometimes I will write the answer in a comment. I'm not aware of any actual rules or standard etiquette though, Sure, the solution here is simple enough to make in a comment.